# Аналог в LINQ для SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2

Tags: c#, linq

Есть два объекта DataTable datatable1 и datatable2. Как получить на выходе результат LINQ запроса аналогичный SQL-ному `SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON condition` в новом объекте DataTable? Как делать сам `INNER JOIN` и даже `OUTER JOIN` ясно.

```
from table1 in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
  join table2 in datatable2.AsEnumerable() 
  on (int)table1["anID"] equals                
     (int)table2["anID"]
  select new
  {
     A = (int)table1["A"],
     B = (int)table1["B"],
     C = (int)table2["C"],
     D = (int)table2["D"]
  };
```

А вот как получить результат в новом DataTable, **не перечисляя при этом поля** пример не попадается.

P.S. Вопрос не о работе с БД, а о возможностях c# + linq

Comment: @3per Вам действительно нужно вполнить `INNER JOIN` между таблицами из **разных** баз данных `datatable1` и `datatable2`?

Comment: максимум `select new  { table1, table2}` иначе только вручную поля указывать

Comment: @Bald `INNER JOIN` между таблицами из **разных** баз данных `datatable1` и `datatable2`, с разных SQL серверов - это задача решаемая или через AsEnumerable, что нееффективно, или созданием, например, [Linked Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/ms188279.aspx). Так что вожно выяснить случайно ли здесь `datatable1` и `datatable2`

Comment: @Oleg, что-то мне кажется вы оба не в ту сторону куда-то пошли :-D

Comment: from a in db.Orders join b in db.Users on a.UserId equals b.Id select new { a, b }- из одной базы данных db

Comment: Товарищи, забудьте пожалуйста о базах данных. В моём вопросе их нет.

Comment: @Grundy опубликуйте свой комментарий в качестве ответа

Comment: @Grundy, как вы предлагаете, я получу коллекцию элементов анонимного типа. Подскажите, как же их потом в DataTable преобразовать? Может стоит завести неанонимный тип, в конструктор, которого передавать table1, table2. В конструкторе в цикле формировать одну DataRow из всех элементов... короче, я запутался )))

Comment: @3per, ну в примере в вопросе вы вполне себе получаете коллекцию элементов анонимного типа. А зачем вам именно `DataTable`? _Может стоит завести не анонимный тип, в конструктор_ - все зависит от того что вы хотите делать с этими элементами потом.

Comment: @Grundy, потом надо в сторонний компонент передать именно DataTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как нужна именно *DataTable*, то первоначально нужно создать ее и добавить колонки. Судя из вопроса вы хотите добавить все колонки из первой таблицы и из второй. Для этого можно воспользоваться следующим кодом.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

foreach(DataColumn column in table1.Columns){
    table.Columns.Add("table1_"+column.ColumnName, column.DataType)
}
foreach(DataColumn column in table2.Columns){
    table.Columns.Add("table2_"+column.ColumnName, column.DataType)
}
```

Теперь в новой таблице колонки из обеих таблиц и можно добавлять строки.

```
var rows = from table1 in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
           join table2 in datatable2.AsEnumerable() 
           on (int)table1["anID"] equals                
              (int)table2["anID"]
           select table1.itemArray.Concat(table2.itemArray);
```

Получили список массивов которые можно добавлять в DataTable.

```
foreach(var row in rows){
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

В итоге получили table со всеми нужными строками.

Answer (score 1):

Для объединения таблиц можно использовать метод **[DataTable.Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Например, есть таблица t1:

```
id      c11
-----------
1       11
```

и таблица t2:

```
id      c21
-----------
1       21
```

Для того чтобы объединить эти таблицы пишем

```
var t3 = new DataTable("t3");
t3.Merge(t1);
t3.Merge(t2);
```

Результат

```
id      c11     c21
-------------------
1       11      -
1       -       21
```

---

Код для примера

```
// #r "System.Data"
using System.Data;

DataTable table(string name, params DataColumn[] columns) {
    var t = new DataTable();
    t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)) { AutoIncrement=true, Unique=true });
    foreach (var c in columns) t.Columns.Add(c);
    return t;
}
void print(DataTable t) {
    Console.WriteLine(
       String.Join(
          "\t\t", 
          t.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName)));
    foreach (var r in t.Rows.OfType<DataRow>())
       Console.WriteLine(
          String.Join(
             "\t\t", 
             r.ItemArray.Select(v => v != DBNull.Value ? v : "-")));
}
var t1 = table("t1", new DataColumn("c11", typeof(int)));
var t2 = table("t2", new DataColumn("c21", typeof(int)));
t1.Rows.Add(1, 11);
print(t1);
t2.Rows.Add(1, 22);
print(t2);
var t3 = new DataTable("t3");
t3.Merge(t1, true);
t3.Merge(t2, true);
print(t3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Хороший ответ на вопрос есть вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215233/return-all-columns-in-anonymous-linq-join

Т.е. выборку осуществляем вот так:

```
var result =
            (from table1 in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
             join table2 in datatable2.AsEnumerable()
             on (int)table1["anID"] equals (int)table2["anID"] into allColumns

             from rows in allColumns
             select new
             {
                 first = table1,
                 second = rows
             });
```

А данные обрабатываем вот так:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
     Console.WriteLine
     (
       "{0} {1}", 
       item.first["Имя колонки из 1-й таблицы"],
       item.second["Имя колонки из 2-й таблицы"]
     );
 }
```